# CS1525 C# Invalid expression term ')'

Tags: c#

Trying to print something like - Generations: 50

```
static void Generations(int value = 50)
{   
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tGenerations: \n", value);
}
```

Here is main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Generations(value:);
    //ExitProgram();
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified anything after `value:`. If you specifically want 50, you can either specify it (`Generations(50)`, `Generations(value:50)`), or since it's the default value, just call the method without the parameter (`Generations()`).

Comment: You should just use `Generations();` or `Generations(50)` or `Generations(value: 50)`.

Comment: @John, I have tried that, however it doesn't output 50, just "Generations: "

Comment: @Youssef13 all three ways do not output 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing here is in your main.

```
Generations(value:);
```

On this line here you should either define a value or leave it empty as you have created a default value when you defined your method.  Another issue you are having is you are calling [Console.Writeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) incorrectly.  With [Console.Writeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_)  you have to define the positions of where you want to place the additional details.

The code below will work:

```
static void Generations(int value = 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tGenerations: {0}\n", value);
}
```

**Working examples:**

Using default value

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Generations();
    }
```

Using defined value

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Generations(50);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried both ways, but neither give the default value when run.

Comment: My apologies please see update to my answer

Comment: I've commented out all the other parts of the code, other than the code I have provided

Comment: I have updated my answer, it will give the desired output

Comment: Oh I just saw the update you posted, and I think that worked! Thanks!